# Convert bitmap to icon

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I am trying to convert bitmap into icon. But there is some error as the resultant file is just blank.

```
private void btnCnvrtSave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(sourceFile);  //sourceFile = openfiledialog.FileName;
    IntPtr Hicon = bmp.GetHicon();
    Icon myIcon = Icon.FromHandle(Hicon);

    SaveFileDialog sfd = new SaveFileDialog();
    sfd.Title = "Save Icon";
    sfd.Filter = "Icon|*.ico";
    sfd.ShowDialog();

    FileStream fileStream = new FileStream(sfd.FileName, FileMode.OpenOrCreate);
    myIcon.Save(fileStream);
    fileStream.Flush();
    fileStream.Close();

    MessageBox.Show("Image is converted successfully!");

    //Process.Start(sfd.FileName);
}
```

I've tried a lot to figure-out the problem but couldn't.
Please tell me where the problem is.

Comment: Have you checked that `myIcon` contains valid data?

Comment: pls take a look at here http://www.codeproject.com/KB/GDI-plus/safeicon.aspx

Comment: @EnigmaState your comment could make for a decent answer instead

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The only problem with this code is that it supports bitmap images upto 128x128.

It yields a blank ico file if the size of bitmap is greater.

Answer (score 17):

Please use **DestroyIcon()** after `GetHicon()` to prevent memory leak.

```
[DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
extern static bool DestroyIcon(IntPtr handle);
```

Docs: [Bitmap.GetHicon Method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.bitmap.gethicon%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Comment: Is myIcon.Dispose() enough or do we have to do what you told?

Comment: Isn't there a portable way to do this?

Comment: To understand when to use `Icon.Dispose()` or `DestroyIcon()` look at [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30979653/icon-fromhandle-should-i-dispose-it-or-call-destroyicon) and [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9892851/win32-destroyicon-vs-icon-dispose).

Answer (score 8):

This article describes how to convert a bitmap to an icon.

http://www.go4expert.com/forums/showthread.php?t=19250

It looks very similiar to your one:

```
using (Cbitmap = new Bitmap(sourceImage.Text))
{
    Cbitmap.MakeTransparent(Color.White);
    System.IntPtr icH = Cbitmap.GetHicon();
    Icon ico = Icon.FromHandle(icH);
}
using (System.IO.FileStream f = new System.IO.FileStream(destinationFldr.Text + "\\image.ico", System.IO.FileMode.OpenOrCreate))
{
    ico.Save(f);
}
```

Try it out.

EDITED: Added the using statements.

Answer (score 2):

Also, this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4042488/how-to-save-bitmap-as-icon) links to [how to convert an image to an icon](http://www.dreamincode.net/code/snippet1684.htm), which may lead you in the right direction.

Notice, however, that the code as written needs to be modified to avoid a handle leak. But the [solution](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.bitmap.gethicon.aspx) is also linked in that question.