# Win32.DestroyIcon vs. Icon.Dispose

Tags: c#, garbage-collection, dispose

I have this line of code:

```
System.Drawing.Icon icon = System.Drawing.Icon.FromHandle(shinfo.hIcon);
```

A few lines later, after icon is used I have the line:

```
Win32.DestroyIcon(shinfo.hIcon);
```

However when running a static analysis on my code it says there is a potential for Resource_Leak from icon. I am wondering will it make any difference if I call the dispose method:

```
icon.Dispose();
```

rather than the Win32.DestroyIcon() that is being used right now. Is there any difference between them? I am just maintaining this code so I am not sure if there was any special intnetion by the original developer to use Win32.DestroyIcon.

Comment: Duplicate of [Icon.FromHandle: should I Dispose it, or call DestroyIcon?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30979653/icon-fromhandle-should-i-dispose-it-or-call-destroyicon)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The static analysis is triggering because you aren't disposing the "IDisposable resource".

I would recommend sticking to the managed version throughout, and using `icon.Dispose()`.  This will (internally) take care of calling `DestroyIcon` for you, but stick to the pure managed API throughout.

`Win32.DestroyIcon` is really intended more for use with icons you're receiving as an `IntPtr`, not for use with an `Icon` instance that is managed by the framework entirely.

Comment: Actually, `icon.Dispose()` only destroys the icon if the (private) boolean `ownHandle` is true, and that depends on the way the the managed icon object was constructed. Specifically, [`Icon.FromHandle(..)` sets that boolean to false](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Drawing/commonui/System/Drawing/Icon.cs,3a4e2c70109d46bc) and so [`Icon.Dispose()` does nothing at all](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Drawing/commonui/System/Drawing/Icon.cs,8d050d7603efcc48).

Comment: This answer is wrong. When using `Icon.FromHandle()`, calling `Dispose()` on the resulting icon **will not** call `DestroyIcon` and you will have a resource leak.

Answer (score 4):

I have had NO END of grief in this area - I've been trying to animate a form's icon (and consequently the one in the task bar) without it leaking resources.

When I disposed of the icon (as suggested on MSDN) resources leaked, when I used "DestroyIcon" all subsequent updates failed. This code below shows everything in the correct order.

API Declaration:

```
[System.Runtime.InteropServices.DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
extern static bool DestroyIcon(IntPtr handle);
```

FINALLY the solution:

```
IntPtr iconHandle = dynamicBitmap.GetHicon();
Icon tempManagedRes = Icon.FromHandle(iconHandle);
this.Icon = (Icon)tempManagedRes.Clone();
tempManagedRes.Dispose();
DestroyIcon(iconHandle);
```

Also posted in this question:
[Icon.FromHandle: should I Dispose it, or call DestroyIcon?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30979653/icon-fromhandle-should-i-dispose-it-or-call-destroyicon/33801377#33801377)