# Cannot convert type 'System.Drawing.Image' to 'System.Drawing.Icon'

Tags: c#, image, vb6, vb6-migration, converters

I was migrating a VB6 application to C# using the [VBUC](https://www.mobilize.net/visual-basic-upgrade-companion) but I got this error:

Cannot convert type 'System.Drawing.Image' to 'System.Drawing.Icon'
and my code was:

```
    this.Icon = (Icon) ImageList1.Images[0];
    this.Text = "Edit Existing Level";
```

Which is the fastest in-memory way to solve this?

Comment: You will need to use a [constructor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.drawing.icon.-ctor?view=netframework-4.7.2). Or see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8174393/convert-bitmap-to-icon)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I wrote an extension method which converted the image to a bitmap and then to an icon:

```
public static class MyExtensions
{
    [DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
    extern static bool DestroyIcon(IntPtr handle);

    public static System.Drawing.Icon ToIcon(this System.Drawing.Image instance)
    {
        using (System.Drawing.Bitmap bm = (System.Drawing.Bitmap)instance)
        {
            System.Drawing.Icon copy = null;
            
            // Retrieve an HICON, which we are responsible for freeing.
            IntPtr hIcon = bm.GetHicon();

            try
            {
                // Create an original from the Bitmap (the HICON of which must be manually freed).
                System.Drawing.Icon original = System.Drawing.Icon.FromHandle(hIcon);

                // Create a copy, which owns its HICON and hence will dispose on its own.
                copy = new System.Drawing.Icon(original, original.Size);
            }
            finally
            {
                // Free the original Icon handle (as its finalizer will not). 
                DestroyIcon(hIcon);
            }

            // Return the copy, which has a self-managing lifetime.
            return copy;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks @r-j-dunnil

Comment: Be careful when using that piece of code! The icon will leak memory if you will not dispose it manually! `When using this method, you must dispose of the original icon by using the DestroyIcon method in the Windows API to ensure that the resources are released.` 
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.drawing.icon.fromhandle

Comment: @DerApe I fixed the resource leak. Thanks for pointing that out.