# Creating a high quality ico file programmatically

Tags: c#, .net-4.0

I'm trying to create a high quality icon (means: [suitable for Win Vista/7/8](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa511280.aspx)) from a PNG file programmatically in C# for use as shortcut icons. Since the Bitmap.GetHIcon() function doesn't support these kind of icons, and I want to avoid external dependencies or libraries, I'm currently using a slightly modified ICO writer I found [here on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11448060/368354%20%22%22).
I have working code but I'm experiencing some glitches in the way Windows displays these icons.
The relevant code is:

```
// ImageFile contains the path to PNG file
public static String IcoFromImageFile(String ImageFile) {
    //...       
    Image iconfile = Image.FromFile(ImageFile);

    //Returns a correctly resized Bitmap        
    Bitmap bm = ResizeImage(256,256,iconfile);                
    SaveAsIcon(bm, NewIconFile);

    return NewIconFile;

}        

// From: https://stackoverflow.com/a/11448060/368354
public static void SaveAsIcon(Bitmap SourceBitmap, string FilePath) {
    FileStream FS = new FileStream(FilePath, FileMode.Create);
    // ICO header
    FS.WriteByte(0); FS.WriteByte(0);
    FS.WriteByte(1); FS.WriteByte(0);
    FS.WriteByte(1); FS.WriteByte(0);

    // Image size
    // Set to 0 for 256 px width/height
    FS.WriteByte(0);
    FS.WriteByte(0);
    // Palette
    FS.WriteByte(0);
    // Reserved
    FS.WriteByte(0);
    // Number of color planes
    FS.WriteByte(1); FS.WriteByte(0);
    // Bits per pixel
    FS.WriteByte(32); FS.WriteByte(0);

    // Data size, will be written after the data
    FS.WriteByte(0);
    FS.WriteByte(0);
    FS.WriteByte(0);
    FS.WriteByte(0);

    // Offset to image data, fixed at 22
    FS.WriteByte(22);
    FS.WriteByte(0);
    FS.WriteByte(0);
    FS.WriteByte(0);

    // Writing actual data
    SourceBitmap.Save(FS, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Png);

    // Getting data length (file length minus header)
    long Len = FS.Length - 22;

    // Write it in the correct place
    FS.Seek(14, SeekOrigin.Begin);
    FS.WriteByte((byte)Len);
    FS.WriteByte((byte)(Len >> 8));

    FS.Close();
}
```

This compiles and works, but with one problem. Windows displays the icon on the shortcut incorrectly. I do this also programatically, but it occurs even if I do it manually (via File Properties, Change Icon). The problem is that the icon is cut off (the image itself displays correctly). It depends on the image, but usually only around 20% of the actual icon is shown. If I open the file in an image viewer like XNView it displays completely and correct, but MS Paint doesn't.
I made this screenshot, along with a correctly displayed icon for comparison

[image]

I suspect the error lies in the ICO saving method, but even after comparing them to normally displayed ICOs in a Hex editor, the header gets written correctly but the PNG image part itself seems different. Has anyone an idea? I also welcome better, less hacky solutions.

Comment: Have you tried flushing your `FS` prior to reading it's length?

Comment: I posted code that writes multi-image ICO files [in this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/29502697/24874).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your ico file is set to save the length of the embedded bitmap with only 16-bit precision, but the PNG file is too large (larger than 65535 bytes) so the length record overflows.

I.e. the following lines are incomplete:

```
// Write it in the correct place
FS.Seek(14, SeekOrigin.Begin);
FS.WriteByte((byte)Len);
FS.WriteByte((byte)(Len >> 8));
```

You could add these lines:

```
FS.WriteByte((byte)(Len >> 16));
FS.WriteByte((byte)(Len >> 24));
```

As a matter of cleanliness and performance, I'd generally avoid all those separate writes and just use the write overload with the byte array parameter.  Also, instead of the somewhat tricky Save-To-File then seek, you might consider a Save-To-MemoryStream then a single Write for the header (which can now use the PNG's length in bytes) and a single write to copy the PNG data from the memory stream to the file.

Another point you really should address is **disposing `IDisposable` resources**.  Even if you don't need to yet since you haven't encountered any problems, it will bite you someday and if you have even a fairly small codebase with all kind of undisposed disposables you'll have a very hard time finding the source of your leak and/or deadlock.  In general: *Never* call `Close` unless you really can't avoid it - instead wrap your `FileStream` in a `using` block.  Similarly, `Image` and `Bitmap` are disposable and allocate native resources, though at least you can't get any locking issues with those (AFAIK - but better to be safe than sorry).

Comment: Thank you, that solved it. I would have never figured that out. And thanks for the suggestions, I'm definitely going to look into implementing them.